# std::bind2nd and std::bind with bidimensional arrays and arrays of structs

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, bind, bind2nd

I know that C++ have lambdas and std::bind1st, std::bind2nd and std::bind are deprecated.

However, start with the foundations of C++, we can understand better new features.

So, I start with this very simple code, using an **array of int**s:

First example: with **std::bind2nd**

```
int array1[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 40 };
int c1, c2, c3;

c1 = count_if(array1, array1 + 7, bind2nd(greater<int>(), 40));
c2 = count_if(array1, array1 + 7, bind2nd(less<int>(), 40));
c3 = count_if(array1, array1 + 7, bind2nd(equal_to<int>(), 40));
cout << "There are " << c1 << " elements that are greater than 40." << endl;
cout << "There are " << c2 << " elements that are lesser than 40." << endl;
cout << "There are " << c3 << " elements that are equal to 40." << endl;
```

Second example: with **std::bind**

```
greater<int> big;
less<int> small;
equal_to<int> equal;

c1 = count_if(array1, array1 + 7, bind(big, _1, 40));
c2 = count_if(array1, array1 + 7, bind(small, _1, 40));
c3 = count_if(array1, array1 + 7, bind(equal, _1, 40));
cout << "There are " << c1 << " elements that are greater than 40." << endl;
cout << "There are " << c2 << " elements that are lesser than 40." << endl;
cout << "There are " << c3 << " elements that are equal to 40." << endl;
```

In both cases the output is:

```
There are 2 elements that are greater than 40.
There are 3 elements that are lesser than 40.
There are 2 elements that are equal to 40.
```

How can I do the same with bidimentional arrays like below: 
(I want to made the same operations with the 2nd coordinate)

```
int array2[7][2] = { { 1, 10 }, { 2, 20 }, { 3, 30 }, 
                     { 4, 40 }, { 5, 50 }, { 6, 60 }, { 4, 40 } };
```

And with arrays of structs like this:

```
struct st
{
    char c;
    int i;
};

st array3[] = { { 'a', 10 }, { 'b', 20 }, { 'c', 30 }, 
                { 'd', 40 }, { 'e', 50 }, { 'f', 60 }, { 'd', 40 } };
```

In this case, I want to do the same operations with the field 'int' in the array of structs.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Learning (the usage of) `std::bind1st`, `std::bind2nd` or `std::bind` won't help you understand new features.

Comment: @cpplearner, I agree with you. I only mentioned lambdas because are an alternative way to do the job, but today, I'm interested in using std::bind2nd and std::bind with the data structures I mentioned i.e. bidimensional arrays and arrays of structs. That's all I want to know by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bind1st`, `bind2nd` and their brethren are deprecated in C++11 and outright removed in C++17. Just in case you didn't know this.

With `bind`, the solution is fairly straightforward, you can use the fact that `bind` expressions are composable and that you can use `bind` to extract a data member (`placeholders` omitted for brevity):

```
auto gr = count_if(array3, array3 + 7, bind(greater<>{}, bind(&st::i, _1), 40));
auto ls = count_if(array3, array3 + 7, bind(less<>{}, bind(&st::i, _1), 40));
auto eq = count_if(array3, array3 + 7, bind(equal_to<>{}, bind(&st::i, _1), 40));
```

With `bind2nd` it's not that easy. You need to declare a function object (can't use a function) that has several typedefs. You can use `binary_function` to ease this:

```
struct my_greater : binary_function<st, int, bool>
{
    bool operator()(st const& l, int r) const {
        return greater<>{}(l.i, r);
    }
};
```

Then you can call

```
auto old = count_if(array3, array3 + 7, bind2nd(my_greater{}, 40));
```

In C++11 you cam employ lambdas:

```
auto XI = count_if(array3, array3 + 7, [](st const& l){ return l.i > 40});
```

[demo of all](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/MfE4bfHRC5fbKLbv)

---

If you have C++11 or newer available, it's almost always the better choice to use lambdas. It's not just a "good default", you'd have to really contort the situation for `bind` to be a better solution.

Comment: Thank you my friend. Without any doubt you are a **GREAT** C++ programmer.