# How to replace std::ptr_fun with std::function and std::ref

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

I'm trying to learn the new features of C++11 and I have this code:

```
void print(int t, string separator)
{
    cout << t << separator;
}


int elements[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 40 };
string delim = " - ";

for_each(elements, elements + 7, bind2nd(ptr_fun(print), delim));
```

Output:

```
10 - 20 - 30 - 40 - 50 - 60 - 40 -
```

About ptr_fun,  [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ptr_fun) site says:

*This function and the related types are deprecated as of C++11 in favor of the more general **std::function** and **std::ref**, both of which create callable adapter-compatible function objects from plain functions.*

Can someone rewrite the example above without ptr_fun and with the functions recomended for C++11?

Thank you

Comment: I think most would probably prefer an `std::ostream_iterator` in this case, totally obviating the `std::function` usage. YMMV depending on application. :) See [here](http://ideone.com/yJnbFo).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most C++11 way would probably be to use a lambda (or a ranged for)

```
for_each(elements, elements + 7, [&delim](int val){ print(val, delim); });
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/k3da8mTa7zLKG4dY)

ranged for:

```
for(int x : elements)
    print(x, delim);
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/juNlSRIyI9eznhvQ)

You could use `std::bind`:

```
for_each(elements, elements + 7, bind(print, placeholders::_1, delim));
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Locvry6W8oGYq0BJ)

But in this case, you could rewrite the whole thing as

```
copy(elements, elements + 7, ostream_iterator<int>(cout, delim.c_str()));
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/5BwnZ658KBZ3Lraq)

---

If you absolutely want to use `std::function`, you can modify the above examples to do so:

```
for_each(elements, elements + 7, function<void(int)>([&delim](int val){ print(val, delim); }));

for_each(elements, elements + 7, function<void(int)>(bind(print, placeholders::_1, delim)));
```

It is pretty pointless unless you *need* type-erasure, though.

Comment: I understand that lambdas are the preferable way to solve the problem, and I already know `std::bind` but what I need to know now, is how to use `std::function` and `std::ref` using my function `print`  without using lambdas.

Comment: @user7140484 I can add an example with `std::function`, but `std::ref` needs `bind`/`async` or `thread` (or make_pair/tuple). And your `print` doesn't accept a reference so it doesn't make sense to use `std::ref` anyway.

Comment: Not wanting to abuse of your patience, could you please answer my other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40524697/stdbind2nd-and-stdbind-with-bidimensional-arrays-and-arrays-of-structs. Tank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You do **not** use `std::function` here. It makes no sense.

`std::function<...>` is a type  that many callable objects can be converted *to*. It makes sense to use this type for a variable or a function argument that should accept a callable object, especially when type erasure is desirable (e.g. when your function cannot be a template).

It does *not* make sense to create an `std::function` temporary and immediately pass it to a standard algorithm like `std::for_each`. Standard algorithms generally accept all kinds of callable objects, including any you could create `std::function` *from*. So  `std::function` would be nothing but a redundant middleman.